# ¿Cómo puedo filtrar los nombres que tengan dos vocales consecutivas en su nombre con SQL?

Tags: sql-server

Tengo un listado de nombres como este:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Seguro que os son familiares ya que son los usuarios de jsonplaceholder. En el fondo los nombres me son indiferentes. En mi caso práctico son otros y en una cantidad muy superior. Necesito filtrar los nombres que contengan mínimo dos vocales seguidas. Por ejemplo, en el listado de arriba serían válidos los nombres "Leanne" pues lleva el grupo "ea". También lo sería "Clementine Bauch", pues su apellido lleva "au", sin embargo no lo sería "Ervin Howell".

Yo creé este código:

```
declare @cadena varchar(5)='aeiou'

select Nombre from (
   select Nombre, (
    select iif(sum(s.combi)>0,1,0) from (
        select 
            charindex(substring(@cadena,t1.n,1)+substring(@cadena,t2.n,1),lower(nombre))Combi
        from 
            (values(1),(2),(3),(4),(5))t1(n),
            (values(1),(2),(3),(4),(5))t2(n)
        )s
)[¿Cumple?] 
from 
   #tmp
)p 
 where [¿Cumple?]=1
```

Este código genera todas las posibles combinaciones de dos vocales, es decir, 5 vocales y cada una de ellas con las 5 vocales, un total de 25 posibles combinaciones. Luego con la función "charindex" busco esas posibles combinaciones dentro de los nombres de usuarios. En caso de que la suma de los resultados sea mayor que 0 lo doy por bueno, en caso contrario lo descarto. Funciona perfectamente y no es extremadamente lenta, a pesar de estar generando la tabla de combinaciones dentro de la propia consulta y comparando las 25 combinaciones con cada nombre, algo que me parece muy ineficiente. Sería cuestión de extraerla a una tabla externa. Me preguntaba si es posible hacerlo de algún otro modo, y si es posible sin recurrir a PATINDEX y expresiones regulares. Necesito algo más analítico.

Anexo los nombres como texto:

```
Leanne Graham
Ervin Howell
Clementine Bauch
Patricia Lebsack
Chelsey Dietrich
Mrs. Dennis Schulist
Kurtis Weissnat
Nicholas Runolfsdottir V
Glenna Reichert
Clementina DuBuque
```

Comment: Puedes poner los nombres como texto en vez de como imagen?

Comment: Hola Luis, ya los tienes como texto. Disculpa.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Puedes usar el operador `like` directamente sobre una construcción que realice todas las combinaciones de vocales, sin usar índices sobre una cadena, lo que agrega tiempo de ejecución.

Por ejemplo, podemos crear todas las combinaciones con una sentencia como:

```sql
select v1.vocal + v2.vocal
  from            (values ('a'),('e'),('i'),('o'),('u')) v1(vocal)
       cross join (values ('a'),('e'),('i'),('o'),('u')) v2(vocal)
```

Valiéndonos de esta construcción, podemos encontrar las coincidencias haciendo un `inner join` de la tabla con esta construcción utilizando el operador `like` como condición de coincidencia:

```sql
select #tmp.Nombre
  from #tmp 
       inner join (           (values ('a'),('e'),('i'),('o'),('u')) v1(vocal)
                   cross join (values ('a'),('e'),('i'),('o'),('u')) v2(vocal)
                  ) on #tmp.Nombre like '%' + v1.vocal + v2.vocal + '%'
```

Hablando de eficiencia, creo que para encontrar las coincidencias no tienes de otra que comparar cada nombre con todas las combinaciones posibles.

No he realizado el análisis, pero creo que dada la pequeña cantidad de combinaciones de vocales, es probable que almacenar esta información en una tabla no agregue ninguna mejora y probablemente yo preferiría tener todo en la misma consulta, por simplicidad del código, aunque no sería complicado crear una tabla con la información, por ejemplo:

```sql
if OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#diptongo', 'U') is not null drop table #diptongo;

select v1.vocal + v2.vocal vocales
  into #diptongo
  from            (values ('a'),('e'),('i'),('o'),('u')) v1(vocal)
       cross join (values ('a'),('e'),('i'),('o'),('u')) v2(vocal);

select #tmp.Nombre
  from #tmp 
       inner join #diptongo on #tmp.Nombre like '%' + #diptongo.vocales + '%'

drop table #diptongo;
```

Comment: Gracias jachguate por tu solución.

Comment: Me ha gustado la forma en que haces las comparaciones sin necesidad de utilizar charindex, muy inteligente. Gracias.

Answer (score 1):

Dices sin usar expresiones regulares, pero es que no veo forma más fácil de lograrlo. Para ello se usa [LIKE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/like-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16&redirectedfrom=MSDN)

```
SELECT nombre
  FROM tabla
  where nombre LIKE '%[aeiou][aeiou]%'
```

- `%` para cualquier serie de caracteres anteriores (desde cero a N)
- `[aeiou]` que le siga alguna de estas letras (las vocales)
- `[aeiou]` que continue con otra de estas vocales
- `%` y que la palabra termine con cualquier serie de caracteres (desde cero a N)

Comment: Yussef, gracias por tu solución, pero no me sirve. El enunciado del problema lo decía claramente, nada de regex. Naturalmente tienes razón, no hay forma más fácil de hacerlo. Ahora imagina que no existiera el operador LIKE 

Comment: @JoséManuel Ok, una lastima no te sirva mi respuesta. La dejaré de todas maneras por si otro usuario busca el mismo problema y no tiene la restricción de tu caso

Answer (score 1):

Desgraciadamente, sin utilizar `LIKE` o `PATINDEX` las soluciones no serán sencillas.

Existe la posibilidad de hacerlo con una tabla de números que permita ir comparando las letras consecutivas para ver si ambas son vocales. Sin embargo, esto puede funcionar con cadenas cortas, pero puede ser más intenso con cadenas largas. Dejo el ejemplo de como hacerlo enviando el código a una función en línea para poder optimizarlo.

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.TieneVocalesDuplicadas(
    @cadena varchar( 8000) -- valor máximo de varchar
)
RETURNS TABLE WITH SCHEMABINDING -- Ayuda al motor a identificar que no usaremos tablas físicas
AS
RETURN
WITH 
E(n) AS( -- 10 filas
    SELECT n FROM (VALUES(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0))E(n)
),
E2(n) AS( -- 10 x 10 = 100 filas
    SELECT a.n FROM E a, E b
),
E4(n) AS( -- 100 x 100 = 10,000 filas (suficientes para varchar 8000)
    SELECT a.n FROM E2 a, E2 b
),
cteTally(n) AS(
    SELECT TOP( LEN( @Cadena) - 1) -- Limitamos el número de filas generadas
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) + 1 n  --Empezamos desde el segundo caracter
    FROM E4
)
SELECT @cadena cadena -- regresamos el valor en caso de cumplir la validación
WHERE EXISTS( SELECT n -- si existe cuando el valor actual y el anterior sean vocales
              FROM cteTally 
              WHERE SUBSTRING( @cadena, n, 1) IN( 'a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u')
              AND   SUBSTRING( @cadena, n-1, 1) IN( 'a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u'));
GO
```

Y la función se puede utilizar de forma sencilla con `APPLY`

```
CREATE TABLE #tmp(
    nombre  varchar(100)
);
INSERT INTO #tmp
VALUES('Leanne Graham'),
        ('Clementine Bauch'),
        ('Ervin Howell'),
        ('Patricia Lebsack'),
        ('Chelsey Dietrich'),
        ('Mrs. Dennis Schulist'),
        ('Kurtis Weissnat'),
        ('Nicholas Runolfsdottir V'),
        ('Glenna Reichert'),
        ('Clementina DuBuque');

 SELECT * -- Consulta para comparar resultados
 FROM #tmp
 WHERE nombre LIKE '%[aeiou][aeiou]%';

 --CROSS APPLY limita a que solo regresen las filas con resultados. 
 --Con OUTER APPLY se regresarían todas.
 SELECT cadena AS nombre
 FROM #tmp
 CROSS APPLY dbo.TieneVocalesDuplicadas( nombre);
```

Comment: Gracias Luis por tu solución. Coincido contigo que sin utilizar algún patrón regex es extremadamente complicado.

Answer (score 1):

Tu código es una buena solución, y está bien diseñado para buscar todas las posibles combinaciones de dos vocales. No obstante, podría ser más eficiente si utilizas una tabla de combinaciones precalculada, de manera que no tengas que generarla cada vez que ejecutes la consulta.

Sin embargo, si quieres un enfoque analítico y no quieres recurrir a PATINDEX ni a expresiones regulares, puedes utilizar una técnica basada en la función LAG de SQL Server. Esta función permite acceder a los datos de la fila previa en el mismo conjunto de resultados, lo cual nos permitirá buscar pares de vocales consecutivas de manera eficiente.

Primero, necesitaremos transformar los nombres en una tabla de caracteres. Luego, con la ayuda de la función LAG, podemos buscar vocales consecutivas.

Aquí está el código SQL que haría esto:

```sql
WITH caracteres AS (
    SELECT 
        nombre,
        LOWER(SUBSTRING(nombre, v.number, 1)) AS letra,
        LOWER(SUBSTRING(nombre, v.number+1, 1)) AS siguiente_letra,
        v.number AS posicion
    FROM 
        #tmp
    JOIN 
        master..spt_values AS v ON v.type = 'P' AND v.number BETWEEN 1 AND LEN(#tmp.nombre)
    WHERE 
        LOWER(SUBSTRING(nombre, v.number, 1)) IN ('a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u')
), 
pares_vocales AS (
    SELECT 
        nombre,
        posicion,
        CASE WHEN siguiente_letra IN ('a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u') THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS par_vocal
    FROM 
        caracteres
)
SELECT 
    nombre
FROM 
    pares_vocales
GROUP BY 
    nombre
HAVING 
    SUM(par_vocal) > 0
```

Este código crea primero una tabla de caracteres, teniendo en cuenta solo las vocales y su siguiente letra. Luego, crea una segunda tabla que indica si cada vocal está seguida de otra vocal (1) o no (0). Por último, agrupa por nombre y selecciona solo los nombres que tienen al menos un par de vocales consecutivas.

Espero que esto te ayude a optimizar tu consulta y a encontrar una solución que se ajuste a tus requisitos.

Comment: Me parece muy buena tu solución. En cierto modo se parece a la mía, y sí, yo también utilizaría una tabla precalculada, de hecho lo mencionaba en mi consulta, para agilizar el proceso. Gracias Dev por tu solución.